# JS no multiplica adecuadamente

Tags: javascript

tengo este código y no sé por qué no funciona, en principio no veo ningún error. Gracias y un saludo.

```
<script>
let nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es nombre?");
let sueldo = prompt("¿Cuál es tu sueldo?");
let antiguedad = prompt("¿Cuál es tu antiguedad?");
if (antiguedad > 10) {
  sueldo = sueldo + (sueldo * 0.05);
}
else if (antiguedad >= 5 && antiguedad <= 10) {
  sueldo = sueldo + (sueldo * 0.02)
}
console.log(" Eres " + nombre + " con un sueldo de " + sueldo + " con una antiguedad de " + antiguedad + " anos ")
document.write(" Eres " + nombre + " con un sueldo de " + sueldo + " con una antiguedad de " + antiguedad + " anos ")
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nosotros, segun tu pregunta, tampoco. que quiere decir no funciona?

Comment: debes mostrar cual es tu error especifico recuerda parsear las variables   sueldo = parseInt(sueldo) + (parseInt(sueldo) * 0.05);

Comment: @CristianCamilo muchas gracias me funcionó, no pensé en hacer parseInt a "sueldo + (sueldo * 0.05);" Pensé que en la multiplicación bastaría. Gracias a los demás también, perdón si formulé mal la pregunta.

Comment: Me alegra que te fuincione, lo pondre como repsuesta

Answer (score 1):

Debes parsear las variables que te llegan del cliente , porque puede ser un string y al hacer "+" en vez de sumar concatenas

```
<script>
let nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es nombre?");
let sueldo = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu sueldo?"));
let antiguedad = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu antiguedad?"));
if (antiguedad > 10) {
  sueldo = sueldo + (sueldo * 0.05);
}
else if (antiguedad >= 5 && antiguedad <= 10) {
  sueldo = sueldo + (sueldo * 0.02)
}
console.log(" Eres " + nombre + " con un sueldo de " + sueldo + " con una antiguedad de " + antiguedad + " anos ")
document.write(" Eres " + nombre + " con un sueldo de " + sueldo + " con una antiguedad de " + antiguedad + " anos ")
```

Comment: Gracias por adivinar!!! el error... igual, esta pregunta ya esta respondida en la marcada como duplicada.. ;)

Comment: a el le resolvió el problema, ese es mi unico objetivo